# Get listitems with custom columns and edit them through c# client object model

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, custom-field-types

I am trying to get a collection of .pdf files from a certain document library, as well as their fields and values. I need three of them - DisplayName, "Barcode"(custom) and "Document Type"(also custom).

Currently I am getting the list collection like this

```
 CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml =
                @"<View>
                <Query>
                  <Where>
                    <Eq>
                      <FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type'/><Value Type='Text'>pdf</Value>
                    </Eq>
                  </Where>
                </Query>
              </View>";
            try
            {
                ListItemCollection listItems = CurrentChosenLibrary.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientcontext.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(
                    item => item.DisplayName,
                    item => item["Barcode"],
                    item => item["Document_x0020_Type"],
                    item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments));
                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now, they all load properly. However, changing them like this:

```
                        item["Barcode"] = "Rafal was here";
                        item["Document_x0020_Type"] = "Here as well";
                        item.Update();
```

...does not do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try running this after update:

```
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: God, that took me a bloody hour of trying and figuring out! Thanks so much, eirikb!